# how to make inifinite scrolling using react-query

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query

**Situation**: I want to make infinite scroll for my project. Currently, I'm using `Javascript fetching API` but want to apply `react-query` instead of.

**Problem**: React query is a form of Hook so can't be nested inside of `useCallback`.

> Below codes are my current infinite scroller.

```
function RQInfiniteScrollTable({src}:{src:string}){
    const [page,setPage] = useState(1);
    const [pageData,setPageData]:[pageData:Array<object>,setPageData:any] = useState([]);

    const loadMore = useCallback(async () => {
        const new_page = page + 1;
        setPage(new_page);
        const buffer: Array<object> = [...pageData];
        let moreData:Response|null = await fetch([src,new_page].join("/").trim());
        let moreData_json:object|null = await moreData.json();
        if(moreData_json === null){return;}
        buffer.push(moreData_json);
        setPageData(buffer);
        return ()=>{moreData = null; moreData_json = null;};
    },[pageData]);

    const products:Array<React.ReactNode> = [];
    // @ts-ignore
    pageData.forEach(({title,image,price,category,description},index):void=>{
        products.push(
        <div key={index} className={"infinite-item-card"}>
            <div className={"w-full h-64 relative"}>
                <Image src={image} alt={title} layout={"fill"} objectPosition={"cover"} objectFit={"cover"}/>
            </div>
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            <p>{price}</p>
            <p>{category}</p>
            <p>{description}</p>
        </div>
        );
    });
    return(
    <div className={"w-full grid justify-items-center"}>
        <h1 className={"text-2xl w-fit my-8"}>{"Infinite Scroller"}</h1>
        <div className={"grid"}>{products}</div>
        <InfiniteScroller loadMore={loadMore}/> <-- this node callbacks given `loadMore` function when intersected.
    </div>
    );
}
```

**Question**: how to solve this problem? I want to use `react-query` for better handling, with optimized way. and does query result of `useQuery` trigger re-render of the component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest defining a query that takes the page number as a parameter, and then including that parameter in the query key. Then, whenever you update the page number, react-query will take care of automatically fetching the result. Here's a mock version I've sketched up:

*useGetPaginatedDataQuery.tsx*

```
export const useGetPaginatedDataQuery = (source: string, pageNumber: number) => {
  return useQuery(["paginatedData", pageNumber], {
    queryFn: async () => {
      const response = await fetch(`${source}/${pageNumber}`);
      return response.json();
    },
    enabled: !!pageNumber && pageNumber >= 0,
  }
}
```

*RQInfiniteScrollTable.tsx*

```
function RQInfiniteScrollTable({src}:{src:string}){
    const [page,setPage] = useState(1);
    const pageDataQuery = useGetPaginatedDataQuery(src, page);

    const loadMore = () => setPage((page) => page + 1);

    // The rest of your component
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem! thanks for suggesting above. I created `onChange` state for dependency for Observer's `useCallback`

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient();
export default function RQIS({src}:{src:string}){
    return(
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <_RQIS src={src}/>
    </QueryClientProvider>
    );
}
const fetcher = async (endpoint:string,index:number) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch([endpoint,index].join("/").trim());
        const data = await response.json();
        return data;
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
    }
};
function _RQIS({src}:{src:string}){
    //latestIndex는 요청해야 할 물건의 색인입니다.
    const [latestIndex,setLatestIndex] = useState(0);
    const [onChange,setOnChange] = useState(false);
    const queryStackRef:any = useRef([]);
    const {data,isLoading,isError} = useQuery(["data",src,latestIndex],()=>fetcher(src,latestIndex),{
        onSuccess:(data)=>{
            queryStackRef.current.push(<RQIS_ItemCard key={latestIndex} data={data}/>);
            setOnChange(!onChange);
        }
    });

    const loadMore = useCallback(async ()=>{
        const new_latestIndex = latestIndex + 1; console.log(latestIndex);
        setLatestIndex(new_latestIndex);
    },[onChange]);

    return(
    <div className={""}>
        <div>{queryStackRef.current}</div>
        <InfiniteScroller loadMore={loadMore}/>
    </div>
    );
}
function InfiniteScroller({loadMore}:{loadMore:any}){
    const observerRef:any = useRef(null);
    useEffect(()=>{
        const target:HTMLElement|null = document.getElementById("infinite-scroller");
        if(target === null){return;}
        const intersectionHandler = (entries:any)=>{
            entries.forEach((entry:any)=>{
                if(entry.isIntersecting){loadMore();}
            });
        }
        const options = {root: null, rootMargin:"0px",threshold: 1}
        observerRef.current = new IntersectionObserver(intersectionHandler,options);
        observerRef.current.observe(target);
        return ()=>{observerRef.current.disconnect();};
    },[loadMore]);
    return(<div className={"w-fill h-4 bg-black"} id={"infinite-scroller"}/>);
}
function RQIS_ItemCard({data}:{data:any}){
    if(data === undefined){return(<></>);}
    return(
    <div className={"h-40"}>
        <h1>{data.title}</h1>
        <p>{data.price.toString()}</p>
    </div>
    );
}
```